# Problem in expanding unallocated space available before ubuntu partition. Tried Live USB ubuntu but while resizing

Tags: live-usb, disk-usage, unallocated

[image: Gparterted image after resize using live-USB ubuntu]
GParted 1.0.0

```bsh
$ configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.3

========================================

Device: /dev/nvme0n1
Model:  HFS512GD9TNG-62A0A
Serial: none
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  1000215216

Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  1961206

Partition table:    gpt

Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/nvme0n1p1  Primary 2048    534527  boot, esp   EFI system partition    fat32   SYSTEM_DRV  /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2  Primary 534528  567295  msftres Microsoft reserved partition    unknown     
/dev/nvme0n1p3  Primary 567296  500781055   msftdata    Basic data partition    ntfs    Windows-SSD 
/dev/nvme0n1p4  Primary 500781056   674859007   msftdata    Basic data partition    ntfs    D   
/dev/nvme0n1p8  Primary 674859008   746541055           ext4        /media/vidhyaubuntu/a8912f0f-4099-4cc0-8b94-8d2030fe1510
/dev/nvme0n1p5  Primary 746541056   877860863   msftdata    Basic data partition    ntfs    E   
/dev/nvme0n1p7  Primary 877860864   998166527           ext4        /
/dev/nvme0n1p6  Primary 998166528   1000214527  hidden, diag    Basic data partition    ntfs    WINRE_DRV   
========================================

Set partition name "U" on /dev/nvme0n1p8  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/nvme0n1p8  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/nvme0n1p8 (partition)
start: 674859008
end: 746541055
size: 71682048 (34.18 GiB)
Set partition name to "U" on /dev/nvme0n1p8  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
```

[image: Error in Ubuntu partition after resize]

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are asking, but it looks like you have partition 6, /dev/nvme0n1p6, with an undersized filesystem.  Use the following command to increase the size of that filesystem, even on a running system:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p6
```